# MaxReceivedMessageSize SOAP service

Tags: vb.net, soap, basichttpbinding

When I call my service for the most part its working great but in one part I'm returning a lot of data and I'm getting the following error.

**The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.**

To fix this I googled and found a solution on this site that stated to use the following binding options in my webconfig file.

```
...
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="200000000"
            maxArrayLength="200000000" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

But I'm still getting the original error and I'm not sure why.

Can anyone please help?
Jim

Answer (score 2):

Typical - five minutes after posting I figured it out.

I had used "Edit WCF Configuration" to edit my web.config but I never edited the small app that I was using to test it.

I also had to edit the app.config file of the vb.net app and enter the binding values above.

Sorry for wasting anyone's time.

Jim